# how can I display the result table in a new page by using PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

Try to display the result in a new page, but it doesn't work. there is error after I submit data.Always said defined function. I am very new at programming,  please help me. Thank you.

```
    <html>
    <?php
    //define variables and set to empty values
    $firstNameErr = $lastNameErr = $ageErr = $areaStudyErr = "";
    $firstName = $lastName = $age = $areaStudy ="";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {

       if (empty($_POST["firstName"]))
         {$firstNameErr = "First Name is required";}
       else
         {
         $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
         // check if section only contains letters and whitesapace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstName))
           {
           $firstNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
           }
         }
       if (empty($_POST["lastName"]))
         {$lastNameErr = "Last Name is required";}
       else
         {
         $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);
         // check if section only contains letters and whitesapace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastName))
           {
           $lastNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
           }
         }
        if (empty($_POST["age"]))
         {$ageErr = "Age is required";}
       else
         {
         $age = test_input($_POST["age"]);
         // check if age only contains numbers
       if (!is_numeric($age))
           {
           $ageErr = "Only numbers allowed";
           }
         }
         if (empty($_POST["areaStudy"]))
         {$areaStudyErr = "required section";}
       else
         {$areaStudy = test_input($_POST["areaStudy"]);  }
    }    
         function test_input($data)
    {
         return $data;
    }

    ?>
    <body>
    <h2>Student information</h2>
    <form method="post" action="submit.php" >
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName">
        <span class="error"> *<?php echo $firstNameErr;?> </span>
        <br></br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName">
        <span class="error"> *<?php echo $lastNameErr;?></span>
        <br></br>
        Age: <input type="text" name="age">
        <span class="error"> *<?php echo $ageErr;?></span>
        <br></br>
        Area of Study: <input type="text" name="areaStudy">
        <span class="error"> *<?php echo $areaStudyErr;?></span>
        <br></br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

code in file submit.php, try to use this to display the table result in new page

```
<html>
    <body>
    <table border="1" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3>
    <tr>
    <th>Frist Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Area of Study</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $firstName; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $lastName; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $age; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $areaStudy; ?></td>
    </tr> 
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: post the exact error message. and please don't tell me what you think my name should be.

Comment: Here is the error message
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: firstName in C:\wamp\www\submit.php on line

Comment: is that two files or one? looks like the first block of php will never run as you are submitting to another file, and in that file the values are in the $_POST array

Comment: if i use form validation all in one page, it can run correctly. When I try to display result in a new page, the code show above it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

You must assign $_POST values to the variables at submit.php before displaying them.

E.G.

$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];

Comment: I add the $_POST values at submit.php, but the form skip the validation part, just display result which i enter in the form page

Comment: The validation is located at the wrong script. Put it at submit.php :)

Answer (score 0):

You're making some very basic mistakes here, which lead me to suggest that you might be better off putting your code aside and spend some time on a site like Code Academy first: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php

That being said, your error is caused by trying to use variables in `submit.php` that have never been declared (as the error states). Those variables were declared in the first page (which contains the form), and only exist on **the server** while the page is being processed.

A form submission is a **brand new HTTP request**. Since HTTP is a [stateless protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol), anything that existed during the original request is no longer around. So, to have access to those variables, you need to duplicate the same (or similar) logic that you have on the original page.